# Sound in background mode with the default audio session?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

if i use play sound in device from any method than  `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];` will effect on the sound that i was playing or it will work only if play sound using `AVAudioPlayer`

Answer (score 1):

No! `AVAudioSession` is a singleton class which can be used to set the audio context for your app. it is not specified for `AVAudioPlayer`. #reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/

Comment: it means the every resultant output song is is goes through the AVAudioSession class.